# Monitoring MMS_RECEIVED like SMS_RECEIVED on android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony, mms, wap

So I'm setting up a program that plays a sound that is set when you receive a message, mms or sms. I got it to work with SMS but MMS doesn't do anything. Here is the code for the class that runs the BroadcastReceiver:

```
/**
 * This class overrides the main BroadcastReceiver to play the tone
 * at the given textSoundPath.
 * @author Jesse Stewart
 *
 */
public class TextMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String textSoundPath;     //this is the sound set to play when
                                            //sms or mms is received.

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        MediaPlayer tonePlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            tonePlayer.setDataSource(textSoundPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't set the media player sound!!!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            tonePlayer.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't prepare the tone player!!!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tonePlayer.start();
    }

}
```

I set it up in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".TextMonitor">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.MMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and of course included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
```

I also tried doing the receiver in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".TextMonitor">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".TextMonitor">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.MMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I also tried putting in the receiver:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
```

But that just made nothing work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. On a side note too, why do you put a period before the class name sometimes in the manifest but not others? like android:name=".TextMonitor" and then sometimes android:name="TextMonitor".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You need to specify data scheme also.**

Manifest entry should be

```
<receiver android:name=".PushReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: @dj.lnxss If it solved your issue then please close the question.

Comment: @dj.lnxss  if this is the perfect solution then why don't you accept as answer. PL mark as an Green Tick :p

Comment: @VipulShah Does the MMS or any related data come along with the Intent?  If so, how do you parse it?

Comment: @VipulShah Can this be registered for programmatically?